# Ошибка при загрузке картинок. Laravel 6, Intervention Image

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь создать контроллер, который будет загружать сразу несколько картинок из формы, при этом, ещё и накладывая ватермарк на них, пакетом intervention/image.
Однако же, мне возвращается ошибка

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::make() must be of the type array, object given
```

Код формы:

```
<form action="route('images.upload', $product->id)" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="images[]" class="form-control-file" multiple>
    <button type="submit">Загрузить картинки</button>
</form>
```

Код контроллера:

```
public function upload(Request $request)
{
    $files = $request->file('image');

    foreach($files as $file){
        $image = Image::make($file); // на эту сроку ругается

        $image->save($path);
    }

    return redirect()->route('index');

}
```

Как мне быть с ней?

Comment: Вам же написали в чем проблема `::make() must be of the type array, object given`

Comment: @E_K , это я уже понял, но как мне с ней быть в этом случае?

Comment: Вы правильно подключили библиотеку?
Ошибка ссылается на метод класса `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`

Comment: Курите [документацию](http://image.intervention.io/use/uploads) библиотеки

Comment: @E_K, библиотеку подключал правильно.